# Is the current Rails 3.0.5 and Bundler dependency set wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

On Windows 7 with Ruby 1.9.2-p180 and Rails 3.0.5 installed, if I

```
rails new trytry
cd trytry
bundle install
```

it will show

```
C:\ror\trytry>bundle install
c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/ui.rb:46:in `<class:UI>': uninitialized constant Gem::SilentUI (NameError)
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/ui.rb:2:in `<module:Bundler>'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/ui.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:17:in `initialize'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `new'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from c:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.0/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>
```

only after a

```
gem install bundler
```

or probably a

```
gem update bundler
```

then the `bundle install` will work.  So looks like the Rails 3.0.5 needs a newer bundler which was not listed correctly in the dependency?  Otherwise when I `gem install rails` for 3.0.5, it should have updated bundler as well, is that right?

Comment: In my experience Rails on Windows 7 is only stable using Ruby 1.8.7, especially once you start installing gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an older version of Bundler installed, you will need to run `gem install bundler` to update it to the latest version.

Rails depends on a version of Bundler matching the dependency version of `~> 1.0`. If you've got a version of Bundler installed, such as `1.0.0`, the process of `gem install rails` sees this dependency is matched already and so won't update Bundler. Therefore, you need to run `gem install bundler` to update it to the latest version.

Comment: isn't that what I said in the post?  I am just asking, is some dependency set wrong in the rubygems side

Comment: so, Rails should really set the dependency higher, such as `> 1.0.6` or whatever.  this is what I am asking, not whether I should or should not run `gem update bundler`

Comment: @動靜能量: Yes. Most likely Rails will set this higher when Rails 3.1 comes out.